Термин этот(,) так-то(,) очень-преочень важен
Нужны запятые?

Термин этот(,) так-то(,) очень-преочень важен.


Правильно:
Термин этот, так-то, очень-преочень важен.
Или: Термин этот, так-то вот, очень-преочень важен.
Пояснение

Обособляется в значении междометия со значением "именно таким образом, не как-нибудь иначе". Используется для усиления и подчеркивания сказанного, относится к всему предложению.

Чаще так-то в значении частицы не обособляется, например: Вот так-то лучше.  Обособление возможно  в начале или конце фразы, а также как отдельная реплика. Поэтому в середине предложения можно добавить "вот".

Все три слова (местоимение так, то, частица вот) имеют значение указания или усиления.


Карта слов:
 ТАК-ТО (разг.). 1. нареч. Употр. преимущ. в 
 восклицаниях в знач. именно так, таким образом. 
 Так-то ты меня слушаешь! 2. частица. То же, что 
 так 1 в 10 знач. — Так-то, брат, кобылочка... Нету 
  Кузьмы Ионыча. Чехов. Так-то, было дело! ◊

  Не так-то (разг.) — не очень, не совсем; совсем 
  не, вовсе не. Борис не так-то робок! Пушкин.
  Так-то и так-то (разг.) — при изложении чьей-н. 
  речи употр. взамен передачи содержания. Сделайте, 
  говорит, это так-то и так-то. Рассказал ему: 
  произошло это так-то и так-то.
  Так-то так (разг.) — вводное слово в знач. нельзя 
  не согласиться, конечно, действительно. Так-то 
  так, но ты всё-таки неправ.


Примеры разговорной речи:

Вчера вечером, так-то вот, опять попали под дождь и промокли, а  я ведь предлагал взять зонты.
Завтра, так-то, опять контрольная, этого следовало ожидать.

В использовании разговорного междометия своеобразная особенность авторской речи. В принципе смысл понятен. Представьте, если в конце ответа на вопрос я  буду добавлять фразу с таким междометием, например: В этой теме, так-то вот, интонационный принцип анализа очень важен.  Но это уже пародия.

Аркадий, не говори занудливо!
